# How to use dynamic URL for VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

In Excel, `VLOOKUP` can be used to look up data in a workbook on a remote server over HTTP, for example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, 'https://example.com/[data.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$B$999, 2, TRUE)
```

How can the URL portion of this `VLOOKUP` be specified dynamically? [One answer](https://superuser.com/a/79843/568435) suggested using the `INDIRECT` and `CONCATENATE` functions together, but this doesn't seem to work in my case as I simply get a `#REF!` error and no request is made to the server with the following syntax:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'https://example.com/", "[data.xlsx]", "Sheet1", "'!$A$1:$B$999")), 2, TRUE)
```

The result of the `CONCATENATE` function in this case is the correct syntax:

```
'https://example.com/[data.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$B$999
```

I can only get Excel to make a request to the remote server if the URL is directly entered in the function.

I have also tried putting the full URL in another cell and referencing it in the `VLOOKUP`, but this isn't working either. How can the URL portion of a remote `VLOOKUP` be used dynamically?

Comment: If worst comes to worst you can always concatenate the formula in another cell and use Eval

Comment: It seems like you are limiting yourself to using VLOOKUP then asking why you can't use this to do the thing you want to achieve. 
I would suggest you  reword to ask a more general question about what you are trying to do and what you want the result to be. By all means show what you have already tried, but don't get hemmed in by that. I suspect there are many potential solutions, and Power Query would almost certainly be amongst them

Comment: @AdamV Yes, there are likely several ways to accomplish what I'm trying to do, and this may not be the right approach. I'm a security researcher and I was trying to use an Excel workbook to read sensitive data from other files and workbooks and then exfiltrate the data using these remote VLOOKUPs. The goal here was never to actually read the data from a remote workbook, it was to make a request to the remote server that contained the sensitive data as the file name being requested. I am thinking that dynamic URLs in VLOOKUPs are specifically disallowed to prevent data exfiltration like this.

Comment: @AdamV That being said, I was ultimately able to find a way to bypass this restriction and exfiltrate the data using VLOOKUPs. I reported the issue to Microsoft and will post my findings here once they fix or close the issue. You can see a proof of concept here: https://twitter.com/jdgregson/status/1553679185859686400